# Prevent user from going forward in registration process if fields are not filled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a registration process using *lightning:progressIndicator* and previous and next buttons, I want to force the user to fill required fields before keeping forwards.

Ok, I know this is not kind of Salesforce related, more something like web development/logic, but since it's a Lightning Component, I would like to present it here.

This is the piece of code that should do the magic:

```
if(currentStage === 'step1') {
    if(component.find("selectedRecordType").get("v.value") != '') {
        var currIndex = arrayList.indexOf(currentStage);
        currentStage = arrayList[currIndex+1];
        component.set("v.currentSteps", currentStage);
    } else {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if(!toastEvent) {
            var severity = 'error';
            var title = 'Select a value';
            var message = 'Please select a record type';
            var showSpinner = false;
            helper.showMessage(component, event, severity, title, message, showSpinner);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Edit:

What happens is that when we go to the next step it jumps from step one to two steps above on the progress bar and shows the warning.

[image]

---

As I said, this might be considered a logic issue, and I hope this question won't get closed.

Any suggestions you have will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the component code as well.  I'm assuming you need to stop the save/update from happening.  Also, the `!=` in this line of code may not function as you expect: `if(component.find("selectedRecordType").get("v.value") != '')`.  Try using `if ($A.util.isEmpty(component.find("selectedRecordType").get("v.value")))` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jump between stages was happening because of this:

```
if(currentStage === 'step1') {
    if(component.find("selectedRecordType").get("v.value") != '') {
        var currIndex = arrayList.indexOf(currentStage); <--------- This
        currentStage = arrayList[currIndex+1];
        component.set("v.currentSteps", currentStage);
    } else {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if(!toastEvent) {
            var severity = 'error';
            var title = 'Select a value';
            var message = 'Please select a record type';
            var showSpinner = false;
            helper.showMessage(component, event, severity, title, message, showSpinner);
        }
    }
}
```

*currIndex* is taking the value of *currentStage* list index, and the current stage is getting the value arrayList and *currIndex + 1*. A problem of logic due to copy paste without thinking properly (mental laziness).

So What I di to solve that issue was:

```
let count = 0;
var currIndex = arrayList.indexOf(currentStage); <--------- This
if(currentStage === 'step1') {
    let selectedRecordTypeField = component.find("selectedRecordType");
    if(!selectedRecordTypeField.checkValidity()){
        selectedRecordTypeField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    } else { 
        currentStage = arrayList[currIndex+1];
        component.set("v.currentSteps", currentStage);
    }
    ++count;
}
if(currentStage === 'step2') {
    if(count == 0) {
        if ($A.util.isEmpty(component.get("v.newStudent.Launchpad__Campus__c"))) {
            var severity = 'error';
            var title = 'Select a value';
            var message = 'Please select your Campus';
            var pageReload = false;
            helper.showMessage(component, event, severity, title, message, pageReload);
        } else {
        currentStage = arrayList[currIndex+1];
        component.set("v.currentSteps", currentStage);
        }
    }
}
```

The count variable helps me to control in which moment the warning for Lookup Fields (Lightning Universal Lookup Component) is going to show.

Thanks
Brian Miller for your suggestions about the API $A namespace.

**Shifu sfdcfox**, you pointed me in the right direction.

PS. if you have any suggestions on my solution, I will be happy to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to perform validation, particularly requiredness, is to mark the field as required, then call the appropriate methods:

```
let selectedRecordTypeField = component.find("selectedRecordType");
if(!selectedRecordTypeField.checkValidity()) {
  selectedRecordTypeField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
} else {
  // okay to continue
}
```

Comment: Thank master, I would like to accept your answer, but I edited the question due it seemed that was not expressing the big issue, the problem was that it was jumping one step above, and of course, the message appearing twice, what you suggested helped me with the last one, also I had to found a workaround to show a warning for the lookup fields that are made of custom component (managed package).

So if it's not unappropriated I'll post my partial solution.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Adrian You're welcome to post your own solution, of course. It will surely help those that need it in the future.

Comment: Thanks, if you think the title or something can be improved in order to reach more people with this same issue please let me know.